# Log4j reflecting configuration file changes?

Tags: java, configuration, log4j

If I make a change to a Log4j configuration file, do I have to restart my application for the changes to take affect, or does Log4j notice the changes and reconfigure itself?

Does it do this under some circumstances and not others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch(log4jConfigurationFilePath, delayInmilisecond)
```

You can use above method to reflect changes at log4j config file , if you prefer xml .. If you prefer propery file , you can use `PropertConfigurator.configureAndWatch` method.

Comment: Or `PropertyConfigurator` if you are using a properties file instead of an XML file.